# How can I get a [Glance] Interface Controller / blank slate for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

In the default storyboard for an Apple Watch application, the Interface Controller has a black rectangle at the top with the time, and the Glance Interface Controller has two Groups.

I would like for both to have the viewport completely covered by my imagery, with a background image that exactly fits the Apple Watch viewport, and a UIImageView portraying a partially transparent PNG, rotated and translated.

I've so far tried and failed to find out how to manipulate XCode's UI to delete e.g. the two Groups in the Glance image.

Is fully covering the viewport available for Glances and/or the main interface, and if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is not possible since all glances should basically provide some similar structure.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaGlance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH5-SW1 says: "Xcode provides fixed layouts for arranging the contents of your glance. After choosing a layout that works for your content, use the following guidelines to fill in that content:"

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mean with "similar structure" (fixed layout). The glances have this fixed layout in which you can freely play your elements. But the two groups of the glance can't be moved, resized or whatever.