# How can I transform an image for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, wkinterfaceimage

This question is mentioned in explaining [How can I get a [Glance] Interface Controller / blank slate for Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089008/how-can-i-get-a-glance-interface-controller-blank-slate-for-apple-watch) , but is a separate basic question.

In iOS, if you have a `UIImage`, you can create a `UIImageView` which supports, among other things, rotation, translation, and other transforms. In the Swift that I've seen, you can create a `WKInterfaceImage`, for instance:

```
@IBOutlet var foo: WKInterfaceImage!
```

However, there were no search results matching, for example `WKInterfaceImageView`.

How can I accomplish the work on an Apple Watch that might be done on an iPhone by getting a `UIImageView` from an `Image`? Are old-fashioned `UIImageView`/`UIImage`s still available? Or is the best available method something like computing an image on the iPhone and dynamically offering it to the watch?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot have affine transforms to WKInterfaceImage, one thing that you can do is create your own drawing context, transform context, draw image there and then extract image from the context.

Comment: Thank you, @GeneratorOfOne. A brief Google search turned up Apple's documentation among others, but do you have any specific links to a tutorial?